# ArrayList null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have created an arraylist, and a ListView. I intend to iterate through the ListView, and checking whether they are checked or not, and then add the object (using ListView.getItem()) to my arraylist. however I get a NullPointerException. The ArrayList people_selected, is declared at top of class like this:

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> selected_people;
```

And my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < people_list.getCount(); i++) {
              item_view = people_list.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
                chBox = (CheckBox) item_view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);//your xml id value for checkBox.
                if (chBox.isChecked()) {
                    selected_people.add((PeopleDetails) people_list.getItemAtPosition(i));
                }
            }

        for(PeopleDetails person : selected_people){

            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(person.number, null, sms_message, null, null);        
            }
        ///and now need to write party to file.
```

I get an error at the line

> for(PeopleDetails person : selected_people)

Saying "NullPointerException"
. I take this to mean that the arraylist is null, and cannot figure out why it should be null. Have I declared it wrong at the top of my class? Or is my selection and add method faulty?

Comment: Add "ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_selected = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();

Comment: your use different variable names for arraylist in declatetion and adding to item part?

Comment: Declaring a reference variable to an object does nothing more than reserve space for you to set it to a reference of a real object *at some point in the future*.  Until you set it to a reference, it points to nothing, or null, which causes the null pointer exception when you try to dereference it (purists, I know the unitialised null references points to a null object but for the sake of a simple comment....)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_selected;
```

You declared  and never initialized. Just initialize it before using it. Otherwise `NullPointerException`.

Try to initialize it

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> people_selected= new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();
```

Answer (score 7):

you missed

```
people_selected = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();
```

you have declared it but not intialized.

Answer (score 2):

The code shows that you declare the variable but doesn't show that you initialize it, like this:

```
people_selected = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();
```

Answer (score 2):

You declared **people_selected** but you're using **selected_people**?!
Which is never filled...

Comment: That's just a typo in the question... Thanks though! I've corrected it. :)

Answer (score 0):

The enhanced for loop is roughly of this structure

```
for (Iterator<T> i = someList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {

}
```

An un-initialized Collection `ArrayList<PeopleDetails> selected_people;` refers to `null`.

If you start an enhanced for loop on an un-initialized Collection it will throw `NullPointerException` because of the fact that it calls the iterator `someList.iterator()` on the null reference.

On the other hand if you have an initialized Collection like so

```
ArrayList<PeopleDetails> selected_people = new ArrayList<>();
```

you will notice that the enhanced for loop doesn't throw any `NullPointerException` because of the fact that `someList.iterator()` now returns an iterator and `i.hasNext()` returns `false` just so that the loop doesn't proceed.

**PS:** The enhanced for loop skeleton is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/85206/3094731).

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because you haven't initialised the array

Adding this solved my issue

```
selected_people = new ArrayList<PeopleDetails>();
```